# Why am I getting a "forbidden 403" error when posting serialized javascript via stringcontent to my web api?

Tags: c#, json, api, http, encoding

I have a post api call that works 99% of the time, however when I try to send certain text as part of my json content, I am getting a forbidden error.

It seems it's related to encoding but I've tried a few methods and I'm not getting anywhere.

Here is my code:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logic);
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{_appSettings.ApiServerUrl}/Tool/Save", content);
```

As I said, this code works 99% of the time, but here is an example of a string that doesn't work (even though it is serialized and should be legitimate json:

```
  {
  "Rules": {},
  "Output": "=(\")((\")){=",
  "Type": "Javascript",
  "Description": "Example",
  "Id": 337
  }
```

As you can see, it's escaping the quotation marks and pasting this json into a formatter considers it as valid json. I have even replaced the quotation marks with apostrophes and I'm getting the same error. However, the below json would work:

```
{
  "Rules": {},
  "Output": "This \"is a test\"",
  "Type": "Javascript",
  "Description": "Example",
  "Id": 337
}
```

I initially had an issue with # symbols being passed in the json, but changing **Encoding.UTF8** to **Encoding.Unicode** fixed this, but didn't fix the issue in the above example.

Any help would be much appreciated, I assume I'm missing something very stupid!

Comment: Your code looks ok and "wrong" content should not result in a 403 error. The correct API response would be 400 bad request. So in short: Looks like the server on the other side does something strange and there is no chance to guess what rules are implemented. You should ask the provider of this api.

Comment: a `403 forbidden` shuldn't be returned based on the _content_ of the request. seems like something is going wrong server side that should rather return a `bad request` or similar - i recommend getting in touch with whoever provides the API.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll get in touch with the API provider.

Comment: 403  usually happens because of the firewall settings

Answer (score 1):

After contacting the api provider, it seems that their api was hosted on Cloudflare and this was forcing a captcha because the json content flagged as malicious (I assume because in some cases this contained javascript and html tags). As a captcha was not successful this was always returning forbidden but only in a few specific instances.

Problem solved!